# WritableRaster.getSample() fails to produce output

Tags: java, raster

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("bridge-gs.png"));
            WritableRaster wr = image.getRaster();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            int width = image.getWidth();
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                 int pixelvalue = wr.getSample(x,y,0);
                  System.out.print(pixelvalue);
```

As per title, I upload the image , raster the file but when I attempt to get at the pixel values using getSample() method no output is produced - some numbers briefly flash across screen and then eclipse terminates process without error message. Would be very greatly if someone can explain how to do this successfully or indeed point to some accessible sources of information on the topic as I'm quite at sea here.
I do see some working models for doing this online, but I dont want to just blindly copy something. I'd like to understand whats going wrong here.
If anybody could recommend a book/source that goes through some of this stuff in baby steps I would also be very grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: `some numbers briefly flash across screen and then eclipse terminates` That sounds like output to me.  Are you asking how to pause the display?

Comment: I'm also thinking out loud here: NetBeans has a tab that I can open to see output, even after the process has terminated.  Doesn't Eclipse have a similar feature?

Comment: Yeah the console window, I mean I have a sysout statement so normally it would print to console window but in this case it briefly flashes across window and then the process terminates. That's the best i can describe it .